# Passed pointer becomes 0x1

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on a school assignment and am stuck on this part. To summarize what the code is supposed to do, it is meant to put 100 random integers into a B-Tree and print out the sorted list of numbers. I get my random numbers easily enough and begin to insert them using the following function:

```
void BTree_Insert(BTREE* tree, int* dataInPtr) {
    bool taller;
    NODE* newPtr;
    ENTRY upEntry;

    if (tree->root == NULL) {
        if (newPtr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE))) {
            newPtr->firstPtr = NULL;
            newPtr->numEntries = 1;
            newPtr->entries[0].dataPtr = dataInPtr;
            newPtr->entries[0].rightPtr = NULL;
            tree->root = newPtr;
            (tree->count)++;
            for (int i = 1; i < ORDER - 1; i++) {
                newPtr->entries[i].dataPtr = NULL;
                newPtr->entries[i].rightPtr = NULL;
            }
            return;
        }
        else {
            printf("Overflow error 100 in BTree_Insert\a\n"), exit(100);
        }
    }
    taller = _insert(tree, tree->root, dataInPtr, &upEntry);
    if (taller) {
        newPtr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        if (newPtr) {
            newPtr->entries[0] = upEntry;
            newPtr->firstPtr = tree->root;
            newPtr->numEntries = 1;
            tree->root = newPtr;
        }
        else {
            printf("Overflow error 101\a\n"), exit(100);
        }
    }
    (tree->count)++;
    return;
}
```

The first number enters fine (tree->root would be null at this point), but when the second number is inserted, it calls _insert, which is where my problems start. Here is the code for _insert:

```
bool _insert(BTREE* tree, NODE* root, int* dataInPtr, ENTRY* upEntry) {
    if (root == 0x1) {
        //printf("root is now 0x1");
    }
    int compResult;
    int entryNdx;
    bool taller;
    NODE* subtreePtr;
    if (!root) {
        (*upEntry).dataPtr = dataInPtr;
        (*upEntry).rightPtr = NULL;
        return true;
    }

    entryNdx = _searchNode(tree, root, dataInPtr);
    compResult = tree->compare(dataInPtr, root->entries[entryNdx].dataPtr);

    if (entryNdx <= 0 && compResult < 0) {
        subtreePtr = root->firstPtr;
    }
    else {
        subtreePtr = root->entries[entryNdx].rightPtr;
    }
    taller = _insert(tree, subtreePtr, dataInPtr, upEntry);

    if (taller) {
        if (root->numEntries >= ORDER - 1) {
            _splitNode(root, entryNdx, compResult, upEntry);
            taller = true;
        }
        else {
            if (compResult >= 0) {
                _insertEntry(root, entryNdx + 1, *upEntry);
            }
            else {
                _insertEntry(root, entryNdx, *upEntry);
            }
            (root->numEntries)++;
            taller = false;
        }
    }
    return taller;
}
```

When passing through root, it for some reason becomes 0x1 and I get a read access violation. I have verified that in BTree_Insert tree->root is not 0x1, so I really have no idea what's going on. Any insight as to how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI `(*upEntry).dataPtr` is more commonly written as `upEntry->dataPtr`

Comment: Can you add your structure declarations? In particular, is `NODE.entries` an array or pointer?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].